# C# webbrowser with youtube embedded

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have a C# application that links to videos in our YouTube account. Up until the middle of May this was working perfectly when playing the videos. We are using a WebBrowser control for this purpose.

We now have an issue with our application (which hasn't changed), in that it displays a script error when trying to play the videos.

The error is:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'create', followed by
>
> Object doesn't support property or method 'setconfig'.

The video doesn't then play at all.

We have not changed anything within our application and it does this on multiple platforms.

What would be the cause of this and how could I rectify it?

Kind Regards

Peter Haynes

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve